# How To Add Files Inside Folder, Not The Folder Itself

Tags: git, github

If you're like me and you like folders to hold the contents for branches on GitHub, to look neat and tidy on Windows (or Linux/Mac whatever):

e.g.

```
github -> project -> .git
                  -> gh-pages -> index.html
                              -> assets -> main.css
                                        -> main.js
                                        -> jQuery.js
                  -> dev
                  -> master
```

If you follow my hierarchy you can see that I have files inside gh-pages, but when I use

```
$ git checkout gh-pages
$ git add gh-pages/*
$ git ls-tree -r --name-only gh-pages
```

The files come up! But when I commit and push them to GitHub the parent folder is uploaded inside the gh-pages branch, instead of the files that I added.

Really confused...

*P.S. I'm new to git*

Comment: "If you're like me and you like folders to hold the contents for branches on GitHub" you shouldn't do that.

Comment: I don't like my project folder messy on Windows

Comment: when using `git checkout gh-pages` it will "delete" the unnecessary folder.

Comment: gh-pages is the branch, and inside my windows local folders gh-pages is a folder containing the files I want in the gh-pages branch without the gh-pages folder itself.

Comment: yep, that is why should put the file actually in the gh-pages folder directly at `./` on the gh-pages branch.

Comment: and how do I achieve that with git bash?

Comment: @BlueEyesWhiteDragon, what you're doing is significantly more "messy" than using Git's branches the way they were intended.

Comment: Alright I now understood how git works with files! It's awesome! Sorry being a total noob, don't really use git/ruby and other terminal based programs (unless for SASS to CSS, that's the only time I use Ruby)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how Git works. Only one branch is visible in your working copy at any time. Trying to make it work otherwise is just hurting yourself.

A possible workaround is to have multiple clones of the same repository, each looking at a different branch:

```
github -> project -> gh-pages -> .git
                              -> index.html
                              -> assets -> main.css
                                        -> main.js
                                        -> jQuery.js
                  -> dev      -> .git
                  -> master   -> .git
```

If the branches don't share common ancestry (as is typical for `gh-pages`), you won't even need to track the other branches in each of the clones, so the overhead will be minimal.